# Most efficient way to search in list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list of dicts.

```
people = [
{'name': "Tom", 'age': 10},
{'name': "Mark", 'age': 5},
{'name': "Pam", 'age': 7}
]
```

Which would be the most optimized way in terms of performance to search in list of dicts. Following are different some methods:

```
next((item for item in dicts if item["name"] == "Pam"), None)
```

OR

```
filter(lambda person: person['name'] == 'Pam', people)
```

OR

```
def search(name):
    for p in people:
        if p['name'] == name:
            return p
```

OR

```
def search_dictionaries(key, value, list_of_dictionaries):
    return [element for element in list_of_dictionaries if element[key] == value]
```

Any other method is also welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing this once and that's it? If so than returning once you found the item makes the most sense. If not than use a mapping that is re-usable for following searches as well.

Answer (score 31):

Doing a quick timeit on the functions show that using filter seems to be the fastest of all the methods

`%timeit filter(lambda person: person['name'] == 'Pam', people)`

1000000 loops, best of 3: 263 ns per loop

- Using next produces a time of 731ns
- Using the search method produces a time of 361ns
- And lastly the seach_dictionaries uses 811ns

Answer (score 4):

If you are searching for a single item then this is the "best" approach

```
def search(name):
    for p in people:
        if p['name'] == name:
            return p
```

All the other implementations will iterate over all the items in the list, whereas this one will stop once the item is found

Comment: I don't know that I'd consider this the "best" approach. Sure this will return once you've found the value in the list, but if the value is the last in the list then you'll have iterated through the entire list anyways