# Subsetting based on multiple conditions for python list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

Based on this [Most efficient way to search in list of dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865201/most-efficient-way-to-search-in-list-of-dicts):

```
people = [
{'name': "Tom", 'age': 10, 'att': 12},
{'name': "Tom", 'age': 5, 'att': 12},
{'name': "Pam", 'age': 7, 'att': 23}
]
```

In the above list of dictionaries, how can I get list of ages for dicts with `name == Tom` and `att == 12`? Doing this only subsets for one condition:

```
filter(lambda person: person['name'] == 'Tom', people)
```

I also want solution to work for both python 2.7 and 3.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`filter` doesn't return a list in Python3.x. You should use a list comprehension

```
[x['age'] for x in people if x['name'] == "Tom" and x['att'] == 12]
```

Aside: Searching isn't particularly efficient, but this is down to your choice of datastructure. This is important if you are doing many lookups as the size of the dict also gets larger. You should use a different datastructure or maintain auxiliary datastrutures. This is a similar idea to how indicies are used in databases.

Comment: What about this `list(filter(lambda person: person['name'] == 'Tom' and person['att'] == 12, people))`

Comment: @ksai, then you have a redundant call to list for the Python2.x case

Answer (score 2):

It's a straightforward adaptation from what you posted:

```
filter(lambda person: person['name'] == 'Tom' and person['att'] == 12, people)
```

It's possible that the timings from the other post won't be the same with two conditions (although I doubt it would change which is fastest), so if you're really worried about speed you could redo the timings.