# how to retrive item from inside a list of dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

I have this file structure:

```
server_id = 1
message = "hello bob, how are you?"
a = [
        {
            "server_id": 1,
            "contents:   [
                {
                    "word": "hello",
                    "reaction: "greetings"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

how would I correctly navigate this structure to get the reaction of "greetings" if the word "hello" was used inside a message from server 1?

Comment: `a[0]['contents'][0]['word'] == 'hello'`? At least based on this structure.

Comment: @pstatix. There are many reasons to close this question :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient way to search in list of dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865201/most-efficient-way-to-search-in-list-of-dicts)

Answer (score 0):

```
server_id = 1
message = "hello bob, how are you?"
a = [
        {
            "server_id": 1,
            "contents":   [
                {
                    "word": "hello",
                    "reaction": "greetings"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

for msg in a :
    for contentKey in msg.keys():
            if 'contents' == contentKey:
                if msg[contentKey][0]['word'] in message : #check if the word is in message only then show reaction
                    print("reaction is  :" + msg[contentKey][0]['reaction'])
```

here is how you can retrieve the message

Comment: Can you actually explain what you did?

Comment: A code dump with no explanation is not a very helpful learning tool.

Comment: All he wanted is to navigate to his desired message and check if it is  in message or not .. So ? What is wrong here ?

Comment: I believe my code is self explanatory . I have added comments where ever necessary . anyway that is your perception .

Comment: The question is asking for free code, which merits a close vote instead of an answer. Your answer does not actually explain anything, it just provides a code dump for the lazy. That's just my take on it, but the beauty of this site is that I only get one vote and you're more than welcome to ignore me.

Answer (score 0):

If your result from the server is always same format you can try this approach:

```
if a[0]['contents'][0]['word']=='hello':
    print(a[0]['contents'][0]['reaction'])
```

or

```
format=a[0]['contents'][0]

if format['word']=='hello':
    print(format['reaction'])
```

output:

```
greetings
```