# Using filter to replace search function in Python

Tags: python, filter

To Python lovers and experts,

**My code:**

```
def getAssignee(keyTitle):
    assignee = ''
    for item in assigneeList:
        if(item['title']==keyTitle):
            assignee = item['name']
            break
    return assignee
```

**My intention:** To try out *filter* in python and replace above code with *filter* function. Assignee list is a list of dictionaries.
E.g.

```
assigneeList = [{'title':'Book', 'name':'Davis'},{'title':'TV','name':'Samsung'}]
```

**My reference:** [Most efficient way to search in list of dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865201/most-efficient-way-to-search-in-list-of-dicts)

**My attempt:**

```
assignee = filter(lambda item: item['title']=='TV',assigneeList)
print(assignee['name'])
```

**My Output:**
Not working. Error "Value 'assignee' is unsubscriptable"

**My question:** How to get the assignee name, like how I got from the getAssignee() function?

Comment: What do you mean by `keys[i]` inside the lambda function?

Comment: Very good question :) I have corrected the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `filter` is a filter object, you can handle this several ways, and handling the eventuality of an empty filter

- use `next(.., None)` to get first matching or `None` value

  ```
  def getAssignee(keyTitle):
      assignee = next(filter(lambda item: item['title'] == keyTitle, assigneeList), None)
      return assignee['name'] if assignee else ''
  ```
- collect the items in a list then pic the first

  ```
  def getAssignee(keyTitle):
      assignee = list(filter(lambda item: item['title'] == keyTitle, assigneeList))
      return assignee[0]['name'] if assignee else ''
  ```

The `next` solution if more performant as it don't generates all the filter object, (the `list` will consumes all the filter, and eventually it could be big)

Comment: Excellent comparison. So in the reference link that I've posted in my query, the answer says that search function (e.g. getAssignee) is much faster than using 'next'. However, I do not really care for that :) I just wanted to learn the usage of filter, and your answer is crystal clear

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> assignee = filter(lambda item: item['title']=='TV',assigneeList)
>>> type(assignee)
<class 'filter'>
```

In python 3 `filter` function will return filter object. `filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to the generator expression `(item for item in iterable if function(item))`. So In order to evaluate the items you can call `list(assignee)`